# stack exchange advertisement issue

Tags: bug

I saw an advertisment banner in stackoverflow like:

- electrical engineering: how to increase speaker voice

and i clicked on it, but it just opens it just as iframe:

[image]

It's not the first time i see this issue. (i'm in chrome)

Comment: Next steps - click on an ad in the iframe. Then click on an ad inside the new iframe in the iframe and so on. See when you get a stack overflow.

Comment: @VLAZ I played that game the previous time i faced this issue. it was crazy :p